# How can I remove and reuse axle cap push-nuts?

Tags: repair

What's the best way to remove axle cap push-nuts (from a little dolly or grocery cart) so they can be reused? I think the new wheels came with replacements, but--for the life of me--they seem to have disappeared (and I'd REALLY like to skip a visit to the hardware store for such a small item (two actually). Any clues, PLEASE?!!

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** These axle caps *really* aren't designed to be reused, but they can be if they're removed carefully. i.e., when you get them off, you might find you have to run to the store to get replacements anyway.

Additionally - If the axle you're removing them from has a groove at the end (and I've seen a couple of items that do have a groove), the little metal tangs that hold it in place will catch in that groove and the only way to get them off is to destroy the cap.

---

In order to get the axle caps off, you have to pry, and pry *hard*. You'll want a sturdy, flat-blade screwdriver or a pry bar for this. Stick the pry bar under the cap and twist the bar just a little bit. You may be able to pry straight up, but you're usually prying against the wheel and it'll want to turn, making it difficult to get good slow, steady pressure.

Start at one side and wedge it up just a smidge. Then move 180° around the cap and pry again. Repeat the prying at 180° intervals, moving the cap a millimeter or two each time until the cap comes off.

It's possible that you'll end up needing to pry every 90° around the cap. Imagining there's a compass rose on the cap, pry at North, then South, then East, then West. If you just move around the circle (North, East, South, West) you'll end up getting it uneven and it will get jammed.

The goal is to pull it up as flat and level as possible. If you get it at too much of an angle, it'll jam and not move at all. If that happens, you'll need to grab your mallet and bang it back on until it's flat and square again, then start from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to prevent deformation by driving them off from behind using the old wheel. Hard to say without photos, but try laying a large open-end or adjustable wrench behind the wheel and striking it with a hammer. If there happens to be enough of a gap, try a smaller wrench behind just the cap.

Before you reinstall, tap or pry the locking tabs toward the inside slightly to re-introduce some tension on the axle.

Comment: This may work if it's not a bolt on axle. I've seen them as covers for the bolts and they're just as much of a pain to get off